# How can I put text into a defined box?

Tags: html, css

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pHd77/)

In this jsFiddle I've got two images and then some text. I want it to appear like this:

[image]

note: the images and text should be sitting on the same horizontal axis, the text is not supposed to be higher

So what I'm trying to do is make the text appear over multi-lines within a box with a width of 150. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/pHd77/1/) what you're trying to do?

As you can see I've only changed your CSS a bit by adding a `display:inline-block` to your text container.